# Ruby on Rails project image display issue - on webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone advise on this problem? No clue why uploaded image doesn't appear:

[image]

Comment: Hard to help without any code.

Comment: hi, sorry, I'm new to coding and I find it pretty confusing - project on GitHub https://github.com/jakub4444/Obrazkowo

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- When you upload the image, check the rails log and see if there were any errors during the upload
- Check the actual file in the file system or S3 depending on where you are trying to upload
- Get the image URL from rails console and load it directly by using the URL

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply, I'm afraid the problem is a bit different, though. It's not like I put the image in the rails project in the code, it is done by users via my app (it's like a Pinterest copy), they can upload images with a button. I do this project following the steps at John Elder's book Learn Ruby on Rails, but it still doesn't work. I'd be very grateful for some help. Github https://github.com/jakub4444/Obrazkowo Heroku https://limitless-forest-48188.herokuapp.com/pins